# How to render Onsen element while display is none

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using onsen.io (using AngularJS) to build out a mobile app game and I'd like to add some animation to some elements such as a list. When a user goes to a page that shows a list, I'd like the list to animate down from the top of the screen using jQuery's `.slideDown()` function. However, to do this, I need to set the element to `display: none`. When display is set to none or opacity is set to 0, Onsen-UI does not render the elements.

The only work around I can think of is to render the element with Onsen, then set it to `display: none`, then run `slideDown()`, but with this progression, the border of the list still shows prior to the elements loading. I could potentially change the border color after loading the elements in, but I imagine there has to be a way to render an Onsen element while the display is set to none. Any thoughts?